# Partially Equal strings and the index of the shared charachter

Tags: java, string

If I want to evaluate that two strings are partially equal, I can use contains
like "Hello".contains"heu"

but my question is how to get the indexes of the characters that are equal?

Comment: `int indexOf(String str)`?

Comment: but how can I know the shared string (str) ? contains will only return a boolean?

Comment: `indexOf` returns `int`.

Comment: is that the above will do a case insensitive match?

Comment: @AvinashRaj just make it `int index = s1.toUpperCase().indexOf(s2.toUpperCase())` and you added case insensitivity.

Comment: @Turing85 I have to check if the string is contained first right?

Comment: @Lisa What do you mean by first right?

Comment: @List No `indexOf` returns `-1` if the string is not contained. It's easier just to try!

Comment: ...or to read the documentation

Answer (score 1):

You could use Pattern and matcher classes.

```
String s1 = "Hello";
String s2 = "he";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?i)" + s2).matcher(s1);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.start());
}
```

Output:

```
0
```

Comment: This seems overengineered. Why not use [indexOf(String, int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)?

Comment: no because there isn't a substring `heu` present in s1.

Answer (score 1):

One of the simplest way to do is use `String.indexOf()` method

```
public class StringTest {
        public static void main(String...strings){
            String s="hello";

            System.out.println(s.indexOf("he"));
        }

    }
```

Output `0`

Comment: What if the second string is "heu"?

Comment: I still want it to return true

Comment: so you want it to return true of false ?

Comment: "hello" and "heu" it should be true

Comment: so if i'm not wrong you want to check if heu is present in hello or what please elaborate

Comment: I want to compare "hello" and "heu" and find that they share "he" which starts in 0 in "heu".

Comment: ok so you want to check if if hello and heu both share he .. if true then return at what position he is at hello and heu ?

Comment: `public static void main(String args[])
    {
     String text    = "hello";
     String text2 ="heu";
     

        
        if(text.contains("he")&&text2.contains("he")){
         System.out.println(text.indexOf("he"));
         System.out.println(text2.indexOf("he"));
        }
        else{
         System.out.println("he is not present in one of them or both");
        }

        

    }`

Comment: but I don't know the "he" it is not a constant.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solve it:

```
public static int[] partiallyEqualColumns(String columnAtt1, String columnAtt2)
    {
        int[] sharedColumn = new int[2];
        String att;
        String[] array1 = columnAtt1.trim().split(" ");
        String[] array2 = columnAtt2.trim().split(" ");
        for(int i = 0 ; i < array1.length;i++)
        {
            for(int j =0; j <array2.length; j++)
            {
                if(array1[i].equals(array2[j]))
                {
                    att = array1[i];
                    sharedColumn[0] = i;
                    sharedColumn[1] = j;

                    return sharedColumn;
                }
            }
        }
        return sharedColumn;

    }
```